# HTTP 302 message in TFS build causing failure

Tags: vb.net, tfs, msbuild, azure-devops

At my company we use Visual Studio Online for source control and have an onsite build server running TFS 2013 Update 5 that we use for builds and integration tests. We have an integration build scheduled to run at midnight Sunday through Thursday. On random nights, the build will fail with the following error message:

Please contact your administrator. There was an error contacting the server.
Technical information (for administrator):
HTTP code 302: Found

This message shows up for nearly every source file in the solution.
However, we have never experienced this error when running the build manually during the day.

Can anyone provide any insight as to what might be going on and how I can resolve it?

Comment: Any chance you're running behind a proxy server which is doing funny things? I've seen these kinds of issues happening when the proxy server does some form of rate limiting or re-authentication...

Comment: There is not a proxy server that I'm aware of.

Comment: Then it is is Firewall!?

Comment: If it were firewall i would assume that it would fail during the day as well and not only overnight.

Comment: Without a network trace to see what's actually going on, this is going to be very hard for us to predict. Unless those random nights coincide with service outages in the past weeks. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsoservice/

Comment: Or if your company uploads their backups offsite during that time! In which case you need to schedule a different time.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio service may be maintained from time to time. Check Visual Studio Online Service status first when the error occur from this website: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/support/support-overview-vs.aspx.